# Which Spring module should I use for a command line Spring Boot application that uses RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm working on a simple command line application using Spring Boot. I need it to interface with some REST API using Spring's `RestTemplate`. Should I reference as a dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` or `spring-web`? Will the presence of any of those in the classpath alter the behavior of the Spring Boot application that's supposed to be a straightforward command line application?

Comment: You can do either. Added the starter and excluding the tomcat part is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with what https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/ does.

When you don't want to create a webserver, don't use `-starter-web`.
Use the plain `-starter` to have "naked" boot application and add `spring-web` to have access to `RestTemplate`.

Comment: So, to clarify, the presence of  just `spring-web` won't alter the behavior of a "vanilla" Spring Boot app into a Web app (with embedded server, etc.)?

Comment: I was actually checking that tutorial earlier before asking this question. I misread the `spring-boot-starter` as `spring-boot-starter-web` because `spring-web` goes after it.

Comment: @PsychoPunch yep, `-starter-web` also adds additional dependencies like `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` for the actual server. The autoconfiguration part of boot (which is part of `spring-boot-autoconfigure`, the starters contain no code) should be smart enough to detect that you're not creating a web application. Though presence of `spring-web` seems to be used for that detection. E.g. in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/OnWebApplicationCondition.java